# How to fix graphic -- shaded area on scatter plot lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I would like to remove from the scatter plot figure the area shaded in red (over the dots in the left corner). I want just red lines. Somebody can help me?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))

points = plt.scatter(df_new["aer"], df_new["mean"],c=z, s=20, cmap="Spectral_r") 

plt.fill_between(df_new["aer"], df_new["aer"] - EE, df_new["aer"] + EE, color='red', alpha=0.3)

ax.axline((0, 0), color='r', alpha=0.3, slope=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The plt.fill_between function creates the shadow between the two external lines. You could trace two line instead:

```
plt.plot(df_new["aero_AOT550"], df_new["aero_AOT550"] - EE, color='red', alpha=0.3)
plt.plot(df_new["aero_AOT550"], df_new["aero_AOT550"] + EE, color='red', alpha=0.3)
```

An example output:

[image]